# parity vs geth - language and enterprise variant/adoption

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, quorum

Geth is written in Go (Golang). What language is parity developed in?

Also why do enterprise ethereum such as quorum go with Go-Ethereum (Geth) instead of Parity?

Answer (score 1):

[Parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity) is written in the [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) programming language.

Read this article, ["Why Rust?"](https://medium.com/paritytech/why-rust-846fd3320d3f), by the Parity team on the reasons why they chose rust.

Golang surpasses Rust in terms of community, libraries, open source projects, and tends to be more developer friendly than Rust.

Answer (score 0):

Quorum was a fork of geth mainly because at the time of its creation it was the most popular client. If I remember correctly, Parity was not even announced yet.